# GridView selection focus change when I click on other focusable item on the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-styles

I have a custom GridView in which I am inflating a TextView inside a Linear Layout. In the same layout, under gridview there is a textfield. I am able to select and deselect gridview items with my desired color. My problem arises when I click on EditText after selecting gridview item, it automatically get deselected and comes to normal unselected form.

I am able to understand that, focus is changes for which it is happening however I want to held the focus on griditem as well as edittext. Is there a way?

Below is the code for the list selector for gridview.

```
 <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in selector:

```
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="@color/red"/>
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
   <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
   <item android:color="@color/normal"/>
```

Comment: I am trying to and let you know.

Comment: no Hanan it does not stay selected when I click on textfield....is there any other way?